# What kind of data object is this format?

Tags: javascript, json

I was asked to take some JSON data to display but was given this format instead:

```
{size={XS=32, SM=34, MD=36, LG=38, XL=40, XXL=42}, length={XS=28, SM=30, MD=32, LG=34, XL=36, XXL=38}}
```

This isn't any sort of JSON object that i've seen before. Is it in another format i'm simply not aware of?

My goal is to take that data and create a table like so:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>SM</td>
        <td>MD</td>
        <td>LG</td>
        <td>XL</td>
        <td>XXL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>size</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>length</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>38</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's not JSON, and it's not JavaScript.

Comment: Where are you getting this data from?  Can you have its source give you proper JSON?  If not, you're gonna need to manually parse this string.

Comment: All of you were correct. I was being passed a Java HashMap Object instead... I simply never worked with those so I couldn't identify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nearly JSON, replace = with :, put the double " in.

There is probably an easier way than I have done here, someone with regex skill will do a better job.

```js
var x = "{size={XS=32, SM=34, MD=36, LG=38, XL=40, XXL=42}, length={XS=28, SM=30, MD=32, LG=34, XL=36, XXL=38}}";
var str = x.split('=').join('":').
  split('{').join('{"').split(', ').join(', "');
var y = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(y);
```

Comment: Thank you. Making this the answer as this works. I talked to the folks giving me the data and it was a JAVA object and not a JSON object... I'm asking them to redo it so I don't have to parse the thing.